# Flutter androidx migration warning always showing

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, mobile

I created flutter project before androidx releasing. App always give warning message **Your app isn't using AndroidX**, but i migrated app to androidx with applying all steps. I tried every method, but does not work. I opened android part of flutter project in android studio and then migrate androidx, i added **android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true** line,changed targetsdversion to 28, gradle versions. But when i run flutter project, this warning appear on console.I guess everything okey, but warning does not disappear. I am waiting your helps.

Answer (score 0):

I would give you a workaround if thats all is not working. Umm Okay Create a new flutter project with AndroidX enabled in android studio and then copy libs , assets , modify pubspecs , and all correct the imports. Change Manifest if you did.

Comment: But there are many configurations about firebase and google maps. Your solution is a way but not exact.